# what's the readStream() method? i just can not find it anywhere,

Tags: android, assets

i searched how to use resources under the directory "assets", then i find a snippet:

```
AssetManager assets = getAssets();
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txAssets)).setText(**readStream**(assets.open("data.txt")));
```

i just cannot find what's the readStream method, it is not in the google apis
 i tried to download the newest Java api document, but still can not find it, anybody knows that?

Comment: but the follwing snippet could do that things right:            AssetManager am = getAssets();
    try
    {
        InputStream ins = am.open("testtext.txt");
        byte[] text = new byte[ins.available()+10];
        ins.read(text);
        String str = new String(text, "GBK");
        et01.setText(str);
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
     Log.i("info", "=======================");
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: Can you post a link to where you found this snippet? It's most probably defined by the user, not part of the SDK.

Comment: It's referenced here too: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As @Felix said it is a user-defined method. On the page you linked, they defined readStream like this:

```
  private String readStream(InputStream is) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      int i = is.read();
      while(i != -1) {
        bo.write(i);
        i = is.read();
      }
      return bo.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, had the same question as OP and landed here !

Comment: I think it must have been removed from the docs, but finding it here was very helpful!

Answer (score 16):

This is better solution:

```
private String readStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),1000);  
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line =r.readLine()){  
        sb.append(line);  
    }  
    is.close();  
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It is much faster than *ByteArrayOutputStream* logic.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with aviomaksim.

```
private static String readStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The line **`sb.append(line + "\n");`** would be much faster like **`sb.append(line).append("\n");`**